# Maintain server time even in offline mode (javascript/html5)

Tags: javascript, html, date, timestamp, offline

I am stuck in a design scenario where I have a javascript/html5 based application which runs in **offline mode**. It is browser based and there are crud operations that happen.

Now when in **offline mode** I would like to maintain the **server time** in my application. This server time will be needed for my crud operations etc

How do I maintain the **server time** using **javascript/html5** when running locally?

NOTE : The application contacts the server the first time and downloads some data, so I can fetch the time too.

**

***I cannot calculate the server time by using the device's local time because the user can change the device's time and create fraud entries.***

**

Comment: Why can't you store the server time in a global object?

Comment: Sounds similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4008583/1443797

Comment: I forgot to add that the user can change the device time and create fraud entries. So calculating the server time using the local device's time is not a correct scenario.
So even if the user changes the device's time, we should  maintain the server time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there's no way of stopping users changing the time on the device and you can't contact an online server if you have no network connection.

If a verifiable audit is crucial then you should record the time when the updates hit the server rather than attempting to record the time the updates hit the device.  Of course, nothing is stopping you doing both.